# c++ When does the constructor for a statically allocated object run

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider a class Cow that has an overload constructor
Cow:Cow (int i);

Now I **Statically** allocate 
Cow myCow(4);

Exactly ***when*** is this non default constructor run?
Is this a good practice or are there any gotchas?

Comment: what do you mean by "statically" ? (the word "static" can have different meanings in C++)

Comment: Is this in a function/class/global?

Comment: This is covered by [basic.start], specifically [basic.start.static] and [basic.start.dynamic].

Comment: Interesting side note: you can execute any code you want before `main`. `int dummy = (really_expensive_function(), 0);`

Comment: And globals and statics are definitely not good practices

Comment: @Simple: You're not guaranteed that runs before `main`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the scope of the static.

At file scope the static variable is initialised at some point before `main()` is called. The order of initialisation is not defined, so you must not rely on it. Note that static members of classes are at file scope for the purposes of initialisation timing.

e.g.

```
static X global_x; // initialised before main() is called
```

If the static variable is defined at function scope, it is initialised the first time the program flows over it. Yes, this means that if the function is never called, it is never initialised. Again, for our purposes, functions, methods and static methods are treated equivalently.

e.g.

```
X& func()
{
  static X my_x;  // initialised the first time the program counter gets here
  return my_x;
}
```

appendix for further understanding:

1. File-scope statics in the same translation unit are initialised in top-town order, so their initialisation order is predictable relative to each other. Order cannot be predicted between translation units.
2. Destruction of static objects takes place strictly in reverse order of construction, whatever that may have been. This gives a degree of predictability and means that (for example) a function-scope static may depend on the lifetime of another function-scope static or a file-scope static... provided the function-scope static was not initialised by another file-scope static in a different translation unit :-)

demo:

Here's a little demo to illustrate initialisation and de-initialisation order. Note that the function `make_fox()` is called before `main()`. Care is required.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct chicken
{
    chicken() { std::cout << "chicken" << std::endl; }
    ~chicken() { std::cout << "~chicken" << std::endl; }

};

chicken licken;

class fox;
fox& make_fox();

struct eagle
{
    eagle() { std::cout << "eagle" << std::endl; }
    ~eagle() { std::cout << "~eagle" << std::endl; }

    fox& _fox = make_fox();
};

class fox
{
    fox() { std::cout << "fox" << std::endl; }
    ~fox() { std::cout << "~fox" << std::endl; }

    friend fox& make_fox();

    chicken& _chicken = licken;
};

eagle eagle1;

fox& make_fox()
{
    static fox _fox;
    return _fox;
}


auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
chicken
fox
eagle
Hello, World
~eagle
~fox
~chicken
```

Comment: Globals in the same translation unit are initialised in top-down order.

Comment: IIRC, initialisation happens before the first function in that TU is called, not before `main`.

Comment: @MSalters added a demo to illustrate a function being called by file-scope statics which in turn creates a function-scope static.

Comment: @RichardHodges: How's an example with just one TU relevant to my comment?

Comment: If you follow the initialisation order you will see that make_fox is called before the static eagle1 is initialised. Thus the file scope static initialisers are not guaranteed to be called before the first function in the TU is called. They are guaranteed to be initialised before main is called. That's the only guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer can be found in articles about the *static initialization order fiasco* (e.g. [this one](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)).

For a global variable, initialization (call of constructor) happens before `main()` starts. If you have multiple global variables *in the same* compilation unit (.cpp), initialization happens in top-down order. If you have multiple global variables in multiple compilation units (.cpp), the initialization order is unspecified (random).

Comment: Globals in the same translation unit are initialised in top-down order.

Comment: I've enriched my answer. Thank you.